Usage of "would rather+person+past tense" is for a lost opportunity or an upcoming incident?Or both
I'm not sure when to use the sentence pattern: "would rather + person + past tense."
For example, if I tell someone, "I'd rather you came on Saturday; I'm really busy on Friday," does this mean we're planning the meeting and I am stating my preference? Or does it mean the date is already set and I am saying what I wanted the date to be?
In summary, is the sentence pattern "would rather + person + past tense" used for a lost opportunity or before the event?
For example, "I'd rather you took off your shoes by the door." Has my guest already taken off their shoes, or am I telling them what I prefer to avoid a conflict?

I'd rather you came on Saturday could mean either I would prefer Saturday to Friday or possibly Could you come on Saturday instead of Friday as we arranged? - the first being the most likely.

It's not used for a lost opportunity. I'd rather you came on Saturday can mean the event is being planned and the day is not yet determined. But it could also be (for example) used if the day was set but circumstances have changed and you want to alter the day. If the day is set and unchangeable, you would be more likely to say I would have preferred you to come on Saturday.

But if someone's already done something, you could use "rather" to tell them for next time. This isn't a totally lost opportunity, though, because there is next time.
